# How to intercept scrolling in an EditText by the parent ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager with an EditText. I want all scrolling events to be handled by the ViewPager, not the EditText.
Specifically, I want the EditText to handle clicks etc, but not move events. I tried to implement this by overriding onInterceptTouchEvent in the ViewPager but didn't succeed.
Does anyone know how exactly this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want the `EditText` to scroll on touch events? So the `EditText` will not detect swipes, only presses?

Comment: Exactly! Especially, I want the ViewPager to detect and act on the events made on EditText.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable horizontal scrolling for EditText which seems to be enabled by default:

```
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

And it works! EditText stops intercept touch events from ViewPager, so, any left/right swipes on EditText area (especially, when non-focused) moves ViewPager.

I had the same problem with EditText views on one of ViewPager's fragment and this solution helped me.